# Laravel Route based on query string

Tags: php, laravel

Currently in my **routes.php** file I've got the following:

```
Route::get('import', 'Controller@import');
```

But as for the requests they'd be sent in the following way:

```
/import?flag=0&data={} //flag could be anything from 0-4 & data is json encoded info
/import?flag=5&data={}
/import?flag=6&data={}
```

These are the only 3 requests that I'd have, I'm aware that Laravel supports `where` method on the route but only regular expressions but not on query parameters, is there a solution for this that I'm overlooking?

The expression method would be something like so:

```
Route::get('import?flag={id}&data={data}', 'Controller@importFlag0-4')->where('id', '<=', '4');
Route::get('import?flag={id}&data={data}', 'Controller@importFlag5')->where('id', '5');
Route::get('import?flag={id}&data={data}', 'Controller@importFlag6')->where('id', '6');
```

Comment: query string isn't part of the actual URI for routing, and it wont be

Comment: @lagbox so is their no solution for me on this one?

Comment: not sure why you need different routes for this

Comment: @lagbox It's more of a cleaner code thing rather than being messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @lagbox, why would you need different routes, when you could handle all those routes conditionals in the `import()` method

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $flag = $request->get('flag');
    $data = $request->get('data');
    if ($flag <= 4) {
        $this->importFlagTillFour($flag, $data)
    }
    if ($flag == 5) {
        $this->importFlagFive($flag, $data)
    }
    if ($flag == 6) {
        $this->importFlagSix($flag, $data)
    }
}
```

and declare the called methods in the same class

```
public function importFlagTillFour($flag, $data) {}
public function importFlagFive($flag, $data) {}
public function importFlagSix($flag, $data) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only single way

```
Route::any('import', 'Controller@import');

On controller write the following function.


public function import(Request $request)
    {
        $getData  = $request->all();
        $flag = $getData['flag'];
        $data = $getData['data'];

        $getModelData = ModelName::where('id',$flag);

    }
```